# Проверить каждый элемент массива на удовлетворение условию

Tags: функции, javascript

Реализовать функцию `every(arr, func)`, которая принимает аргументами массив `arr` и функцию `func`. Возвращает `true`, если функция `func` вернет для каждого элемента массива `true`. В функцию `func` нужно передавать аргументами элемет массива, индекс элемента массива и сам массив.

Пример, как должен работать код:

```
// Проверка на то, что все элементы массива - строки
every(['mama', 'mila', 'ramu'], function (arrayItem) {
    return typeof arrayItem === 'string';
}); // true
```

Вот я написал, но не пойму, как в этот фанк впихнуть массив из every.

```
======================================================================
function funk() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) 
            return {
                "arg[i]":arguments[i],
                "i": i

    };
 }
function every(arr, func) {
    return typeof arrayItem === 'string';

}
every(['mama', 'mila', 'ramu'], function funk(arr) {

}); // true
```

Comment: @Yres, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вы неправильно поняли условия, от вас требуется сделать функцию every, которая принимает массив и другую функцию. Если переданная функция для всех элементов массива вернет true, то значит и every вернет true, иначе false. В данном же случае ваша every возвращает:

  ```
  return typeof arrayItem === 'string'; //неизвестная переменная arrayItem?
  ```

А аргументы вообще не используются никак.

- На переданную внутрь функцию налагаются условия, она принимает элемент, индекс и массив. Поэтому ваша функция every должна будет вызвать для каждого переданного элемента массива функцию `func(element, index, array)` с приведенными параметрами.
- В итоге Вам надо только реализовать every, без всяких func:

  ```
  function every(array, func){
      //вызываем для каждого элемента func(element, index, array) и если для всех она вернула true, то возвращаем true, иначе false   
  }
  ```
- Приведенный пример, как должна работать функция, идет в разрез с тем, что описано в условии. Так как по условию она принимает три аргумента, а по примеру только один. С точки зрения логики, скорее всего вместо `func(element, index, array)` правильнее реализовать `func(element)`. Но лучше уточнить у давшего задание.